# Is 'just as' used correctly?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

Jim did x but didn't do y, *despite being **just as** capable of doing so*.

I want the italic part of the sentence to mean that "Jim is as capable of doing x as of doing y." Does it mean so?

Comment: In some contexts it would make a difference whether X and Y are mutually exclusive or not. *Jim married Jane, but he could **just as well have** married Jean*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Should I use "just as well" instead of "just as"?

Comment: Interesting question. Personally, I think by default *He did A, but he could just as well have done B* implies ***it was equally likely***  that he would do B. That's to say, he made an unconstrained / unpredictable choice (being by further implication equally *capable* of doing either)....

Comment: ...That same implication (of the ***outcome*** being effectively "random") can also apply with ***just as easily***, but in some contexts ***just as easily*** can better carry the implication of the ***agent*** being ***equally capable*** of doing either. As, for example, *Jim bought a second-hand Ford Fiesta last week, but he could just as easily have bought a Porsche* (that fact that he could *afford* to do either is being pointed out). Where ***just as well*** more strongly implies *it was just a random choice*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're correct. Jim was capable of doing either x or y. You can replace 'just as' in the sentence with 'equally' without changing the meaning.

> Jim did x but didn't do y, despite being equally capable of doing so.